# Set a shortcut in Atom editor for Go To Definition using go-plus

Tags: atom-editor

How can I set a shortcut in Atom editor for Go To Definition using go-plus. Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

By default, the [go-plus](https://atom.io/packages/go-plus) package uses <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to trigger the *Go To Definition* binding (as can be seen [here](https://github.com/joefitzgerald/go-plus/blob/master/keymaps/go-plus.cson)). This binding will only work in files that use the *Go* grammar. Since <kbd>Cmd</kbd> is only available on Mac OS X, I don't know what keybinding other operating systems will use by default.

To redefine the keybinding, do the following:

- Open the Atom Preferences, select the *Keybindings* section.
- In the *Search* field, type 'go' to filter the list of keybindings.
- Click the *Copy* icon next to the `golang:godef` keybinding.
- Click the *your keymap file* link at the top.

[image: Atom Keybindings]

This will open your `keymap.cson` file. Go to the end of the file and paste the copied content:

```
'atom-text-editor[data-grammar="source go"]:not(.mini)':
  'alt-cmd-g': 'golang:godef'
```

Edit the keybinding to your liking and safe the file.

To verify the new keybinding, open the *Key Binding Resolver* view by selecting the *Packages > Key Binding Resolver > Toggle* menu entry. Open a *Go* file and press the keybinding you assigned, then watch the *Key Binding Resolver* view to see any conflicts.

Comment: the first link is broken

Comment: THe key binding doesn't show up there anymore? I see it on the context menu and it works, but it's not listed on the keybinding list. Has Atom changed how it handles that?